# summarize the results of multiple regressions done on different subsamples of the same dataset

Tags: regression, bootstrap

I want to estimate how robust is the result of a simple correlation test (Y~bX+c) to changes in the number and identity of the observations selected to perform it. For that, I have repeated such correlation many times, each time randomly selecting a different number of observations. E.G. My original data set has 20 observations and I have repeated the same correlation for 100 series of 10 to 20 observations.

Now, I would like to summarize the correlation results in a way that it shows the sensitivity of the parameters to changes in the number and identity of the observations included in the correlation. Any hint?

I have thought of two plots:

One would be a scatter plot of the obtained p value against the number of observations in each iteration

Another would be a scatter plot of the obtained p values against the mean X value of the observations (thus representing observations identity)

Would this be valid/enough?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [why not both?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OawrlVoQqSs)

Comment: I thought of using both, actually. Do you think it would be valid?

Comment: Graphing data is never _in_valid. You could also plot sample size versus sample mean and label the points 1-20, then plot correlation versus sample label in decreasing order (so if sample 19 has the highest correlation, it is furthest to the left). The real question is: **what comparison do you want to emphasize?** All graphs are comparisons. [Maybe a graph is overkill and a table would suffice](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/22/tables-as-graphs-the-ramanujan-principle/). Easy three columns: sample size, sample mean, sample correlation

Comment: p-values *really* wouldn't be my choice for a way to summarize or compare regressions; they're random quantities that don't convey much information of interest. If you're interested in impact on correlations, *plot corrrelations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Graphing data is never invalid. You could also plot sample size versus sample mean and label the points 1-20, then plot correlation versus sample label in decreasing order (so if sample 19 has the highest correlation, it is furthest to the left). The real question is: what comparison do you want to emphasize? All graphs are comparisons. [Maybe a graph is overkill and a table would suffice](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/22/tables-as-graphs-the-ramanujan-principle/). Easy three columns: sample size, sample mean, sample correlation